# filter search not working in php when I tried to send reference through url string

Tags: php

Getting all search results but while using the search filters the page redirects to an blank page with url like `http://localhost/diningcity/res_search?resTitle=Cafe`.

When I try to retrieve the type or location from database using the resTitle (as resTitle is the keyword user is giving input) but it redirects to blank page.

Controller:

```
<?php

class Res_search extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()  {
    parent::__construct();

$this->load->model('common_model');
$this->controllerFile = 'res_search';
$this->table = 't_search';  
}


public function index()
{


}

public function searchAll(){
    $where_clause = "status = 'Y' ";

    if($this->uri->segment(3) == '' && $this->uri->segment(2)!='index' && $this->session->userdata('mode')=='')
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('resTitle', '');
        $this->session->set_userdata('location', '');

        $data['resTitle'] = ''; 
        $data['location'] = ''; 
    }   

    if($this->input->post('hdnSearch')!= ''){
        $resTitle = $this->input->post('resTitle');
        $this->session->set_userdata('resTitle', $resTitle);     

        $location = $this->input->post('location');
        $this->session->set_userdata('location', $location);    

    }
    else{
        $resTitle = $this->session->userdata('resTitle');
        $location = $this->session->userdata('location');            
    }



    if($resTitle!=""){
    $data['resTitle'] = $resTitle;
    $data['location'] = $location;  
    $data['where_clause'] = $where_clause;

    $total_row_res=  $this->common_model->res_count($resTitle,"") ;
    $limit = 4;        
    $config = array();
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."res_search/searchAll";
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['total_rows'] =  $total_row_res;


    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);   
    $pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();        

    $data['total_row_res'] = $total_row_res; 
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3,0);

   $searchList = $this->common_model->search($this->table, $resTitle, $limit, $offset);

   $data['$offset'] = $offset;
   $data['pagination'] = $pagination;
   $data['searchList'] = $searchList;
    }

    else{
    $data['where_clause'] = $where_clause;
    $data['resTitle'] = $resTitle;
    $data['location'] = $location;   
    $total_row_loc=  $this->common_model->res_count("",$location) ;
    $limit = 4;        

    $config = array();
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."res_search/searchAll";
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    //$config['first_url'] = '1';
    $config['total_rows'] =  $total_row_loc;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] =  'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);   
    $pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();        

     $data['total_row_loc'] = $total_row_loc;  

   $offset = (int)$this->uri->segment(3,0);

   $searchList = $this->common_model->searchLoc($this->table, $location, $limit, $offset);


   $data['$offset'] = $offset;
   $data['pagination'] = $pagination;
   $data['searchList'] = $searchList;


    }

    $data['getAllCuisines'] = $this->common_model->getAllCuisines();

    $this->load->view("search_view",$data);

}

}
```

Model:

```
function getAllCuisines(){
  $query ="select cuisine_name from t_cuisines ";
  $result = $this->db->query($query);
  return $result->result();
}
```

View:

```
    <div class="panel-heading">Cuisines</div>
      <div class="scroll">
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($getAllCuisines); ++$i) { ?> 
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>res_search?resTitle=<?php echo $getAllCuisines[$i]->cuisine_name; ?>"><?php echo $getAllCuisines[$i]->cuisine_name; ?></a>
      </div>       
      <?php }?>   
    </div>
```

Comment: What are you asking for? your expected output..

Comment: you'll be redirected to a blank page because your function index() is empty..

Comment: what else can i try ather than showing the value this way         <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>res_search?resTitle=<?php echo $getAllCuisines[$i]->cuisine_name; ?>"><?php echo $getAllCuisines[$i]->cuisine_name; ?></a>  in my view page